# SP Designer - Hiding Tabs on Tab Control Based on Read Only Field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

I have the following JS code which works if I do not make the field read-only, however I need AllUsers to be unable to edit this field.

I tried to use a calculated field instead but this did not work either. The calculated filed is PMOLifecycleStage.

Any ideas on how I can make it work?

```
// Initiate TAB
function setInitiateTab() { 
var v = fd.field('LifecycleStage').control().value(); 
if (v == '(2) Initiate') { 
$('#fd_tabcontrol-1').tabs('option', 'disabled', [2,3,4,5]); 
} else { 
$('#fd_tabcontrol-1').tabs('option', 'disabled', null); 
} 
} 

// Subscribe on status change 
fd.field('LifecycleStage').control().change(function () { 
setInitiateTab(); 
}); 

// Initialize 
setInitiateTab();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Dmitry over at Forms Designer

> In the display mode you should use the following code to get text representation of a field value:
>   fd.field('FieldName').control()._el().text()